# jQuery.ajax filter doesn't work on few selectors

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm using wordpress (4.1) and jQuery 1.11 - I want to load other page content in page I'm right now - using ajax. I can append whole html (width head, meta and all that stuff), I can filter images or spans, but when I'm trying to filter section or #content there is empty response. There are no errors in Console.

jQuery:

```
$('nav a').click(function(load) {
    load.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: jQuery(this).attr('href'),
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(out) {
            result = jQuery(out).find('section');
            jQuery('#change').append(result);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML looks like this:

```
<section id="content">
 ....
</section>
```

I think I tried everything. With "img" instead of section there is content (part of it is from section#content, so it's weird).

Anyone know what can be wrong? I'm using this same code in another wordpress with this same version, and all works like a charm. I don't have any more jQuery libraries loaded.

Comment: and console.dir(out) really shows html with <section> element insider ?

Comment: Mmmm maybe when is a section must get the html(), **jQuery(out).find('section').html();**

Comment: @JesúsQuintana tried, didn't work.

Comment: @johnSmith yup, out shows all html code, with section#content.

Comment: well and what shows console.dir(result) ? what shows console.dir(jQuery(out)) ? there must be something wrong you can find out with simple logging

Comment: jQuery(out).find('section#content'); ???

Comment: I believe `result = $('#content', out);` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If your full html response is:

```
<section id="content">
 ....
</section>
```

then the issue is that `$.find` will only find the descendants of an element, and it will not find the top-level element itself. As an example:

```
$('<p><a>hi</a></p>').find('p') // => []
$('<p><a>hi</a></p>').find('a') // => [{a element}]
```

A quick workaround is:

```
$('<div></div>').append($('<p><a>hi</a></p>')).find('p') // => [{p element}]
```